# How to determine if a variable is exponential in maxima?

Tags: maxima

I want to determine in an expression as `2^n` or `n^2` or `2*n` if the variable $n$ is exponential. So in those cases only the first one would return `true`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy answer is to use `freeof`:

```
(%i1) exponentp(e,n):=not mapatom(e) and 
                      op(e) = "^" and not freeof(n,second(args(e)))$
```

Then:

```
(%i2) map(exponentp,[2*n,n^2,2^n,(n+1)^(a+b), (a+b)^(n+c),2^(3/n+1)],[n,n,n,n,n,n]);

(%o2) [false,false,true,false,true,true]
```

Which is the desired answer, I believe.